# A problem concerning sets cardinality

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $k ≥ 1$ be a positive integer. Find an $\varepsilon > 0$ in terms of $k$, as large as you can, such that the following statement is true.

Consider a family $F$ of subsets of $S = \{1, 2, \ldots , N\}$, where $N > k$ is an integer. If for any $T ⊆ S$ with $1 ≤ |T| ≤ k$ we have $1/2− \varepsilon < \dfrac{| \{X \in F : |X ∩ T|\text{ is odd}\} |}{|F|}<1/2+ ε$, then some set in $F$ contains none of $\{1, \ldots , k\}$.

Comment: Any one feeling to help me a little. I dont even know how to approach.

Comment: Problem M3 from the [PRIMES 2017 problem set](http://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2017/entpro2017usa.pdf)